# Bash - Sitemap test XML, LOC

Tags: xml, bash, sitemap, robots.txt

I've got a bash script which gets all xml files from **robots.txt** file and prints the HTTP Server responses to output file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#usage ./script.sh robots.txt

while read url
do
    urlstatus=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '{http_code}' "$url" )
    echo "$url  $urlstatus" >> results.txt
done < $1
```

Sample of **robots.txt** can look like that:

```
http://www.youraddress.com/file1.xml
http://www.youraddress.com/file2.xml
http://www.youraddress.com/file3.xml
```

Sample of **output**:

```
http://www.youraddress.com/file1.xml 200
http://www.youraddress.com/file2.xml 200
http://www.youraddress.com/file3.xml 200
```

But each XML file has inside **loc** tags.

Inside XML:

```
<url>
<loc>
    http://myother.address.com/
</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.8</priority>
```

All I need to do is to get from each file: file1, file2... each URL from **loc** tags and print also response of HTTP Server.

Does anyone would me get some tips, help with code based on this script ?

Comment: You want the HTTP code and the `<loc>` value from the fetched URL? Instead of the original URL and the HTTP code? Have you tried anything for this? (You are going to have to stop throwing away the document you are fetching as a start.)

Comment: @EtanReisner <loc> values consist of urls so I also want to get the responses of those links. If OK - 200, else 404.

Comment: put it simply, you wish to extract the url inside the loc and do some curl stuff with it?

Comment: @sjsam: Exactly. I want to do a HTTP Response on them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using xmllint --noout "$url" to make sure that the XML doesn't have syntax errors in it.

Robots.text is going to have lines in it like Allow */*, or should, and so you need to fetch out only the ones you want maybe with

```
sed -n -e 's/^ *sitemap: *//p'
```

To process the XML, you could use XSLT, e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
   mlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!--* extract URLs one per line from loc elements;
      * match loc in any namespace (XSLT 1 method):
      *-->
  <xsl:template match="*[name() = 'loc']">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><!--* newline *-->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(you can run this with the xsltproc command).
Or write the whole thing in Perl or python with one of the XML modules.

Don't try and parse XML using the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You could something like below:

```
url=$(wget -q -O - /dev/stdout test.web/xml1.xml | sed -n "/\<loc>/{n;p;q}"); 
#do some curl stuff with the $url as you wish
```

Comment: This assumes that there is only one `location` per xml file.